# Warning в layout'ах

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Выдает вот что:

> Nested weights are bad for performance
>
> Issue: Looks for nested layout weights, which are costly
>
> Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice. When a LinearLayout with non-zero weights is nested inside another LinearLayout with non-zero weights, then the number of measurements increase exponentially.

Что бы это могло значить и как это исправить? Если надо, могу выложить код, но он аналогичен [этому](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html), только вложенный LinearLayout один, а не два.

В общем, вот:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="100dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/selectDeviceText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="@string/selectDeviceLabel" />

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/foundDevices"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonScanDevices"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"                 //<== тут ругается
            android:text="@string/buttonScanText" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/buttonBeep"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/buttonLEDText" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/buttonLED"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/buttonBeepText" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Может, я где в разметке накосячил? Поправте, пожалуйста.

Comment: http://translate.google.com.ua
хотя и без него понятно )

Comment: Я умею читать по-английски. Вопрос в том, как это исправить, не убив представление.

Answer (score 1):

Убери параметр `weight` у вложенного лайаута, так как он один, то вес ему не нужен.
Или удали у всех компонентов, если он у всех одинаковый, то и не нужен.
А так, этож не ошибка, а предупреждение, что производительность ниже и лучше не злоупотреблять.

Comment: Работает, но варнинг все равно висит.

Answer (score -1):

Eclips ругается на параметр android:layout_weight="0" у TextView. Зачем вам android:layout_weight="0" не понятно.

**Update**
Да был не прав.
Сейчас посмотрел получше и думаю нашел решение.
“Вложенные веса мешают производительности” и тут мы видим такую ситуацию. Получается что самый главный LinearLayout разбивает свои дочерние элементы по весам (TextView имеет вес 0, ListView 10, LinearLayout все что ему осталоcь). В свою очередь Вы еще разбиваете последний LinearLayout опять на веса (3 Button имеют вес 1) и в итоге получаем «вложенные веса».
Посмотрите в сторону RelativeLayout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOAD" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
         >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: За тем, чтобы TextView не оказался под ListView. Вы бы хотя бы проверяли, прежде чем отвечать.